# how to update a document from local database using Room Persistence Library?

Tags: android, android-room

Thanks in advance. This is the interface I am using. Update method is not working and all other methods are working.

```
@Insert
void insertMultipleRecord(EnquiriesModel... enquiryEntities);

@Insert
void insertMultipleListRecord(List<EnquiriesModel> enquiriesModels);

@Insert
void insertOnlySingleRecord(EnquiriesModel enquiriesModel);

@Query("SELECT * FROM enquiries")
List<EnquiriesModel> fetchAllData();


@Update
void updateRecord(EnquiriesModel ... enquiriesModel);

@Delete
void deleteRecord(EnquiriesModel enquiriesModel);

@Query("DELETE FROM enquiries")
 void nukeTable();
```

This is the model class I am using

```
@Entity(tableName = "enquiries")

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;

protected EnquiriesModel(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readInt();
    email = in.readString();
    createdon = in.readString();
    childname = in.readString();
    relation = in.readString();
    updatedon = in.readString();
    dateofenquiry = in.readString();
    followup = in.readString();
    channel = in.readString();
    academicYear = in.readString();
    childDOB = in.readString();
    country = in.readString();
    countryCode = in.readString();
    country_name_code = in.readString();
    secodaryContact = in.readString();
    secodaryCountry = in.readString();
    secodaryCountryCode = in.readString();
    secodarycountry_name_code = in.readString();
    priority = in.readString();
    _id = in.readString();
    parentname = in.readString();
    mobile = in.readString();
    schoolid = in.readString();
    enqNote = in.readString();
    labelNames = in.readString();
    labels = in.readString();
    enquiriedPrograms = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<EnquiriesModel> CREATOR = new Creator<EnquiriesModel>() {
    @Override
    public EnquiriesModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new EnquiriesModel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public EnquiriesModel[] newArray(int size) {
        return new EnquiriesModel[size];
    }
};

@NonNull
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(@NonNull int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
private String email;
private String createdon;
private String childname;
private String relation;
private String updatedon;
private String dateofenquiry;
private String followup;
private String channel;
private String academicYear;
private String childDOB;
private String country;
private String countryCode;
private String country_name_code;
private String secodaryContact;
private String secodaryCountry;
private String secodaryCountryCode;
private String secodarycountry_name_code;
private String priority;
private String _id;
private String parentname;
private String mobile;
private String schoolid;
private String enqNote;
private String labelNames;
private String labels;
private String enquiriedPrograms;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "EnquiriesModel{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", createdon='" + createdon + '\'' +
            ", childname='" + childname + '\'' +
            ", relation='" + relation + '\'' +
            ", updatedon='" + updatedon + '\'' +
            ", dateofenquiry='" + dateofenquiry + '\'' +
            ", followup='" + followup + '\'' +
            ", channel='" + channel + '\'' +
            ", academicYear='" + academicYear + '\'' +
            ", childDOB='" + childDOB + '\'' +
            ", country='" + country + '\'' +
            ", countryCode='" + countryCode + '\'' +
            ", country_name_code='" + country_name_code + '\'' +
            ", secodaryContact='" + secodaryContact + '\'' +
            ", secodaryCountry='" + secodaryCountry + '\'' +
            ", secodaryCountryCode='" + secodaryCountryCode + '\'' +
            ", secodarycountry_name_code='" + secodarycountry_name_code + '\'' +
            ", priority='" + priority + '\'' +
            ", _id='" + _id + '\'' +
            ", parentname='" + parentname + '\'' +
            ", mobile='" + mobile + '\'' +
            ", schoolid='" + schoolid + '\'' +
            ", enqNote='" + enqNote + '\'' +
            ", labelNames='" + labelNames + '\'' +
            ", labels='" + labels + '\'' +
            ", enquiriedPrograms='" + enquiriedPrograms + '\'' +
            '}';
}

public EnquiriesModel() {

}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getCreatedon() {
    return createdon;
}

public void setCreatedon(String createdon) {
    this.createdon = createdon;
}

public String getChildname() {
    return childname;
}

public void setChildname(String childname) {
    this.childname = childname;
}

public String getRelation() {
    return relation;
}

public void setRelation(String relation) {
    this.relation = relation;
}

public String getUpdatedon() {
    return updatedon;
}

public void setUpdatedon(String updatedon) {
    this.updatedon = updatedon;
}

public String getDateofenquiry() {
    return dateofenquiry;
}

public void setDateofenquiry(String dateofenquiry) {
    this.dateofenquiry = dateofenquiry;
}

public String getFollowup() {
    return followup;
}

public void setFollowup(String followup) {
    this.followup = followup;
}

public String getChannel() {
    return channel;
}

public void setChannel(String channel) {
    this.channel = channel;
}

public String getAcademicYear() {
    return academicYear;
}

public void setAcademicYear(String academicYear) {
    this.academicYear = academicYear;
}

public String getChildDOB() {
    return childDOB;
}

public void setChildDOB(String childDOB) {
    this.childDOB = childDOB;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getCountryCode() {
    return countryCode;
}

public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
    this.countryCode = countryCode;
}

public String getCountry_name_code() {
    return country_name_code;
}

public void setCountry_name_code(String country_name_code) {
    this.country_name_code = country_name_code;
}

public String getSecodaryContact() {
    return secodaryContact;
}

public void setSecodaryContact(String secodaryContact) {
    this.secodaryContact = secodaryContact;
}

public String getSecodaryCountry() {
    return secodaryCountry;
}

public void setSecodaryCountry(String secodaryCountry) {
    this.secodaryCountry = secodaryCountry;
}

public String getSecodaryCountryCode() {
    return secodaryCountryCode;
}

public void setSecodaryCountryCode(String secodaryCountryCode) {
    this.secodaryCountryCode = secodaryCountryCode;
}

public String getSecodarycountry_name_code() {
    return secodarycountry_name_code;
}

public void setSecodarycountry_name_code(String secodarycountry_name_code) {
    this.secodarycountry_name_code = secodarycountry_name_code;
}

public String getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

public void setPriority(String priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}

public String get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(String _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public String getParentname() {
    return parentname;
}

public void setParentname(String parentname) {
    this.parentname = parentname;
}

public String getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}

public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}

public String getSchoolid() {
    return schoolid;
}

public void setSchoolid(String schoolid) {
    this.schoolid = schoolid;
}

public String getEnqNote() {
    return enqNote;
}

public void setEnqNote(String enqNote) {
    this.enqNote = enqNote;
}

public String getLabelNames() {
    return labelNames;
}

public void setLabelNames(String labelNames) {
    this.labelNames = labelNames;
}

public String getLabels() {
    return labels;
}

public void setLabels(String labels) {
    this.labels = labels;
}

public String getEnquiriedPrograms() {
    return enquiriedPrograms;
}

public void setEnquiriedPrograms(String enquiriedPrograms) {
    this.enquiriedPrograms = enquiriedPrograms;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeString(email);
    dest.writeString(createdon);
    dest.writeString(childname);
    dest.writeString(relation);
    dest.writeString(updatedon);
    dest.writeString(dateofenquiry);
    dest.writeString(followup);
    dest.writeString(channel);
    dest.writeString(academicYear);
    dest.writeString(childDOB);
    dest.writeString(country);
    dest.writeString(countryCode);
    dest.writeString(country_name_code);
    dest.writeString(secodaryContact);
    dest.writeString(secodaryCountry);
    dest.writeString(secodaryCountryCode);
    dest.writeString(secodarycountry_name_code);
    dest.writeString(priority);
    dest.writeString(_id);
    dest.writeString(parentname);
    dest.writeString(mobile);
    dest.writeString(schoolid);
    dest.writeString(enqNote);
    dest.writeString(labelNames);
    dest.writeString(labels);
    dest.writeString(enquiriedPrograms);
}

public static class Labelnames {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("values")
    private List<Values> values;

    public List<Values> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<Values> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public static class Namevaluepairs {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("colourCode")
        private String colourcode;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("name")
        private String name;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("_id")
        private String Id;

        public String getColourcode() {
            return colourcode;
        }

        public void setColourcode(String colourcode) {
            this.colourcode = colourcode;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return Id;
        }

        public void setId(String Id) {
            this.Id = Id;
        }
    }

    public static class Values {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("nameValuePairs")
        private Namevaluepairs namevaluepairs;

        public Namevaluepairs getNamevaluepairs() {
            return namevaluepairs;
        }

        public void setNamevaluepairs(Namevaluepairs namevaluepairs) {
            this.namevaluepairs = namevaluepairs;
        }
    }
}

public static class Enqnote {

    public String staffname;
    public String time;
    public String action;
    public String note;
    public String Id;

    public String getStaffname() {
        return staffname;
    }

    public void setStaffname(String staffname) {
        this.staffname = staffname;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }
}
```

I am calling update like this in fragment.Here enquiriesModel contains the data of mine as per the EnquiriesModel Class. I am adding the data to enquiry model from the edittext fields like this.

```
AppDatabase  sampleDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(getActivity());
 enquiriesModel.set_id(enquiriesModel.get_id());
            enquiriesModel.setEmail(eMail.getText().toString().trim());
            enquiriesModel.setCreatedon(enquiriesModel.getCreatedon());
            enquiriesModel.setChildname(childName.getText().toString().trim());
            enquiriesModel.setRelation(relation1.getText().toString().trim());
            enquiriesModel.setUpdatedon(String.valueOf(tsLong));
            enquiriesModel.setDateofenquiry(dateofenquiry);
            enquiriesModel.setFollowup(followdate);
            enquiriesModel.setChannel(channel.getText().toString().trim());
            enquiriesModel.setAcademicYear(year.getText().toString().trim());
            enquiriesModel.setChildDOB(birthTime);
            enquiriesModel.setCountry(ccp.getSelectedCountryName());
            enquiriesModel.setCountryCode(ccp.getSelectedCountryCodeWithPlus());
            enquiriesModel.setCountry_name_code(ccp.getSelectedCountryNameCode());
            enquiriesModel.setSecodaryContact(mobile2.getText().toString().trim());
            enquiriesModel.setSecodaryCountry(ccp2.getSelectedCountryName());
            enquiriesModel.setSecodaryCountryCode(ccp2.getSelectedCountryCodeWithPlus());
            enquiriesModel.setSecodarycountry_name_code(ccp2.getSelectedCountryNameCode());
            enquiriesModel.setPriority((pri_check.isChecked())?"1":"0");
            enquiriesModel.setParentname(name.getText().toString().trim());
            enquiriesModel.setMobile(mobile.getText().toString().trim());
            enquiriesModel.setSchoolid(currentSchool.getSchoolid());
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String enqNote = gson.toJson(enqNoteArray);
            String programarray = gson.toJson(programArray);
            enquiriesModel.setEnqNote(enqNote);
            String label = gson.toJson(labelsarray);
            JSONArray arraylabel = new JSONArray();
            for(int k =0;k<labellist.size();k++){
                JSONObject objectlabel = new JSONObject();
                objectlabel.put("type",labellist.get(k).getType());
                objectlabel.put("_id",labellist.get(k).get_id());
                objectlabel.put("name",labellist.get(k).getName());
                objectlabel.put("colourCode",labellist.get(k).getColourCode());
                arraylabel.put(objectlabel);

            }
            String labelnamearray = gson.toJson(arraylabel);
            enquiriesModel.setLabelNames(labelnamearray);
            enquiriesModel.setLabels(label);
            enquiriesModel.setEnquiriedPrograms(programarray);
            sampleDatabase.enquiryDao().updateRecord(enquiriesModel);
```

Comment: Please post your code that how you fill the EnquiriesModel object and call `updateRecord` method?

Comment: Please include your fragment code add well. It will be easy to trace your issue.

Comment: @Update by default uses aborting conflict strategy. Consider using @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) and check whether that fullfills your requirements.

Comment: @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)  used this but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to your `@Update` would be to use `@Query`

```
@Query("UPDATE EnquiriesModel SET SOME_FIELD = :value WHERE EXISTING_FIELD = :existingValue;")
void updateStatus(String existingValue, String value);
```

Comment: I need to update the entire document not only a particular field

Comment: you can have some condition in where which ever rows satisfies those conditions will get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

To Update your your data in database, you will have to add your primary key value in that. That will update data with matching rows. As from your above code, you are not sending your id in `enquiriesModel`. You need to get primary key of that row first and then need to add in `enquiriesModel` and then update it.

Missing part is,

```
enquiriesModel.setId(id)
```

`sampleDatabase.enquiryDao().updateRecord(enquiriesModel);`

That will definately work.